# How can I make a column start top of container, and not depend on other columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a grid-layout with BS4.

This is how it looks right now:
[My grid-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjXuV.png)

This is what I'm trying to achieve: [grid-layout I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhTgj.png)

The problem I have is that my sidebar is starting at the same place as main content. I want it to start from the top along with the navbar. I know you can do this if you nest navbar and main content into the same column, but I don't want that since I'm going to make navbar into a partial.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="row">

      <div id="navbar" class="col-md-8">
          Navbar
      </div>

      <div id="main" class="col-md-8">
          Main Content
      </div>

      <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-4">
          Sidebar
      </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

#navbar{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}

#main{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

#sidebar{
  background-color: red;
}
```

[JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/43wwgqrp/34/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to group columns by putting navbar and main-content in one column and the second column for sidebar.

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-8 col-md-8">
    <div id="navbar" class="col-md-12">
      Navbar
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="col-md-12">
      Main Content
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div id="sidebar" class="col-4 col-md-4">
    Sidebar
  </div>

</div><--row-->
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8nwdvss/4/)

Comment: Thank you for a reply, but this is not what I want as I explained in my question.